# (C++,Qt,Linux) converting game map cords to image coords

Tags: c++, linux, qt, math

Alrighty, so basically I get my gaming coords with various Ptrace functions, works well, and I drew up a map, sort of a street view for this 3D game. And placed it onto a qgraphicsscene, with qpixmap, it shows up beautifully, zoomable, panning, all the good stuff. Now I ran into a problem, my player position for a certain position is:X=904.758 Y=9754.3 and the picture coords, are PixX=5453.63 PixY=1205.01, roughly anyway. How would I convert the player position to a Pixel location? I can give more coords if needed. Another location : X=960.784, Y=9728.9...PixX=5426.65, PixY=1218.5.

All this was typed on my phone so if its hard to read I do apologize.

Comment: i think it all depends on how you store the positions. if you just use plain game data, it starts with (0,0) to (y,x). draw the pixmap in the same cordinates and let the graphicsscene/view manage the display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are in 3D, the screen coordinates depend on all three world coordinates. One can assume that z=0 if there are no hills in the scene.

Then the next question to answer is what kind of projection is used. The parallel or central type? And then you would need at least 3 known relation pairs to compute a fourth, the technology was developed in the Renaissance and is called [cross-ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio), the idea is that cross ratios stay invariant under projection.